# Python Equivalent to Scheme Apply

Tags: python, functional-programming, scheme

Does Python have a function equivalent to scheme's apply? I notice that Python's reduce works on functions of two arguments, and applied it recursively, which is very different.

Should I write my own? Is there some module I'm missing?

Comment: Could you describe what functionality you actually need? Not all of us know Scheme.

Comment: @delnan http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's equivalent to Scheme's apply is to use `*` and/or `**` prefixes on the arguments.

For example:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2]
>>> operator.add(*my_list)
3
```

The `*` prefix is used on a sequence for positional arguments and the `**` prefix is used on a dictionary for keyword arguments. (This mirrors their usage in formal parameter declarations.)

Answer (score 2):

While argument unpacking (as shown in Laurence's argument) is the proper way to do what you want (i.e., it is considered best Python style), the exact Python equivalent to Scheme's `apply` is, technically, Python's [`apply`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#apply), even though this is now deprecated.

Comment: I didn't mention `apply` since it's actually been deprecated for a long time: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0290/#replace-apply-with-a-direct-function-call

Comment: I felt it was worth pointing it out because if he had simply went looking for an `apply()` function, he would have found it (and the documentation would have pointed out the new improved way).

Comment: Perhaps he's using Python 3, which no longer has the `apply` function.